# Use javascript to check when an image has updated on the back end

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, frontend

I am updating an image in the filesystem asynchronously. When a user clicks 'upload' they upload and replace the image called "image.jpg". The file will take between 1 and 90 seconds to update on the back end. How can I check when it has finished updating with javascript on the front end?

```
$('#square_image_upload_button').click(function(e){
  $(".image").attr('src', "/images/loading.gif" );
  setTimeout(function () {
    var image_url =  '/image.jpg' + "?" + new Date().getTime();
    $(".image").attr('src', image_url );
  }, 30000);
});
```

Ex. The following code works only when the upload takes 30 seconds or less. Lowering the time on the setTimeout function risks not displaying the image if the upload takes longer then 30 seconds. updating the image with a loop removes the loading gif.

Comment: How do you perform the upload? I'd simply have the serverside script terminate only when the image is done processing. If you're using a form to submit the image, you could handle the submission logic yourself. If you can't or don't want to have the sever-side script wait, I'd do another request to check the status of the image, or just handle the onerror event for the image.

Answer (score 0):

If the image is going to either 404 (or some other error) if it's not uploaded yet or be there if it is, the easiest way would be to add a `load` and `error` event on to your image. If it triggers the `load` event, you know it's good. If it triggers the `error` event, it wasn't good and you should check again later.

I would actually do this with a new image instead of the one you display to your end-user. Once it's loaded, then put that URL out for your end-user.

Something like this:

```
function checkImage(url, loadedCallback) {
    const $img = $('<img>')
        .once('load', () => loadedCallback)
        .once('error', () => setTimeout(checkImage, 10000));

$('#square_image_upload_button').click(function(e){
  $(".image").attr('src', "/images/loading.gif" );
  var image_url = '/image.jpg';
  setTimeout(() => checkImage(image_url, function () {
    $(".image").attr('src', image_url);
  }), 30000);
});
```

What this should do is after your first timeout triggers (in 30 seconds), it'll try checking the image. If the image is loaded, it'll call the callback, which will set it for your front-end image.

If it errors, it isn't ready, so it'll wait 10 seconds and try again. It'll then continue that every 10 seconds until it finally works, which it'll then call your callback.

Comment: Thanks! This actually helped me solve the problem. The solution was to simply add a ".done" function to my ajax call and get it to change the image once the image has finished uploading:

.done(function () {
    console.log('SUCCESS');
     $(".image").attr('src', ''/image.jpg' );
  });  

This allowed the image to change as soon as the back end finished processing it.

Answer (score 0):

We attempt to load the image. If it fails, we try again. You can set a rough "timeout" to the whole process.

```
$('#square_image_upload_button').click(function(e){
  $(".image").attr('src', "/images/loading.gif" );

  loadImage($(".image"), '/image.jpg', 30000);
});

function loadImage($el, url, timeout) {
    if (timeout <= 0) return;

    $el.one('error', function() {
        const wait = 1000;

        setTimeout(function() {
            loadImage($el, url, timeout - wait);
        }, wait);
    });

    $el.attr('src', url + '?cache=' + Date.now());
}
```

As I originally commented, you may consider revising the server-side code rather than repeatedly make requests for the image.